# visual c# button opens file without specifying drive

Tags: c#

I work for an IT company where we all carry around flash drives that have our most used programs on them.In my spare time I am hoping to create a "main menu" item that is kind of a fun and convenient way to access these files. I am working on creating this using Visual Studio 2013 and using visual C# windows forms. I have come across a snag however that I can't seem to find a workaround for. I am by no means fluent in C#, but I need to have a button on the windows form open a file without specifying what drive it comes from. I understand that I have to specify a path, but as these will be stored on the flash drives of myself and my coworkers I cannot foresee that the path will always begin with E:. Depending on what USB slot the drive is plugged into it could be N: or F: or the like. I have provided an example below:

Using what I currently know I am opening files using this line of code:
System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("C:/Users/Myname/Desktop/Asmodeus/Anti-Virus/Anti-Virus Installers/avast_free_antivirus_setup.exe");

Is there any way possible I can have the file open simply from
System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("Asmodeus/Anti-Virus/Anti-Virus Installers/avast_free_antivirus_setup.exe"); 
or something of that nature?

Thanks in advance.

There must have been some mis-communication when I asked my question previously. what I am looking to do is open an executable file via a button click on the windows form using a relative path. I am not able to specify the absolute path because the application will be run from a flash drive and therefore will change depending on what USB slot it is currently inserted into.

What I am hoping to accomplish is insert a line of code that will allow me to open an executable file that is located in the \bin\debug folder along with the application itself. I have a picture for clarification but apparently do not have enough reputation to post it. Thank you and sorry for the earlier confusion.

Comment: Look at the `Environment.GetFolderPath` method for getting some standard paths.  You just have to know the standard path you want and it will give you the absolute path on the current system and, in some cases, for the current user.

Answer (score 0):

Usually you can just use `Environment.GetFolderPath` ([MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/14tx8hby%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)) to give you what you need.  It doesn't do absolutely everything, but if you need `Desktop` and the like, that is plenty.

Depending on the target version of .Net, the [SpecialFolders](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.environment.specialfolder%28v=vs.90%29.aspx) exposed are not all there.  It may turn out that you need more than they provide, but in your case it doesn't sound like it.

If there is more you need that is not covered in the default, check out this project.  I'm sure there are others like it, but it does a little more than the default BCL version, using the API directly.  It is at least something to read and learn (and translate from vb.. use an online translator, very quick).  I haven't looked at it, but it seems like you are learning this c#/.net thingy, so it might be helpful

[This article is about accessing Windows special folders.](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/24308/Accessing-All-of-Windows-Special-Folders)

```
These folders include your “Favorites”, “Cookies”, system libraries and the like. 
Here is code, including a large number of constant definitions, plus documentation, 
allowing access to and creation of these folders.
```